# How to disable hot module replacement in webpack for production

Tags: webpack

How does one remove all references of HMR when bundling for production?

My production Webpack config has no references to HMR and yet in the browser debugger the client is constantly making a xhr call to /__webpack_hmr

Can anyone shed a light on this?

-- my config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'master/jsx/App')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    cache: false,
    devtool: 'sourcemap',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                compact: false
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }, {
            test: /\.woff|\.woff2|\.svg|.eot|\.ttf/,
            loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=10000'
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: What command are you using to run your Webpack build? Can you post your production Webpack config?

Comment: Hi Ambros, gulp is invoking webpack.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you setup your config. I have a node environment variable that tells me if i'm running in production mode or not. If it isn't production, I setup webpackDevMiddleware with the following in my server.js.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    app.use(connectLiveReload());
    let config = require('./webpack.config'),
        compiler = webpack(config);

    app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        noInfo:     true,
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath
    }));

    app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition, you might want to control the middleware client on the front end from firing calls:

```js
entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
]
```

by controlling that input using `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'` in the webpack.config.js.

Refer to [running webpack in production.](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/)

Answer (score 2):

You might try making sure all of the browser windows you have open to your website are using an updated bundle.

I was having the same problem, except in my case I saw the GET /__webpack_hmr calls on my server because I made my server print all the request methods and paths.

Turns out, I had a different browser window open that I hadn't noticed, which was running my dev bundle; it was making the requests.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to disabling the code with an env variable, I would propose to completely remove HMR code at build, this will also minimize your final bundle and sourcemaps

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip-block can be used for that